# Задержка времени перед распечаткой

Tags: windows, print, java

Мне нужно, чтобы программа печатала текст на принтере. Для этого использую `PrinterJob`. Но всегда перед печатание есть задержка в 15с. В чем может быть проблема?

Использую `Thermal Custom TG2480 printer`. Теcтировал на `WindowsXP`.

возможно проблема в принтере или в драйверах?ибо теперь на Custom TG2840 задержки
, а на FujitsuFTP639 с задержкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно странно, очень сомневаюсь, что проблема в `JRE` *(я предполагаю, что печать с помощью остальных программ происходит быстро, а при печати с помощью `PrinterJob` появляются задержки).*

Если это действительно так, то лично я бы проверил какой-нибудь канонический код на печать *(типа [**этого**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PrintinJava2PrinterJob.htm))* и попробовал бы посмотреть внимательнее на вызовы `setPrintable`, `setPageable` и попробовать их по отдельности.

---

**Было бы неплохо, если бы вы показали свой код.**